# How can I access Azure Cosmos DB Analytics Store using Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

As of now, the only way to access the Cosmos Analytical store is via Synapse as per the documentation over here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction

Is there any way I can access this data analytics store in Azure Databricks without Azure Synapse link? If not, is anything in the works?

Comment: This is not possible and there are no plans to enable this.

Comment: @MarkBrown - So, the only option going forward with this is going to be Azure Synapse?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @MarkBrown, Would you like to post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible and there are no plans to enable this. The only option going forward with Cosmos DB's analytical store is to use Synapse Link.